# Tefillin with chipped paint

Tags: halacha, tefilin, color

Is there a problem with wearing tefillin whose paint has started to chip off?  Would such a situation require one to get the tefillin repainted?  Can someone still be yotzei by tefillin whose paint is chipped?

Comment: Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43499

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a *halacha l'Moshe miSinai* that the *r'tzu'os* must be black (*M'nachos* 35a), and this is a requirement for valid *t'fillin*. The straps must be re-blackened if the paint becomes scratched or abraded (*Bach* OC 32:25). Abrasions are especially common (if not readily noticeable) in the vicinity of the knot of the *shel yad*, and special attention should be paid to that area of the *r'tzu'a* (*Mishna B'rura* 33:19).

The *Bi'ur Halacha* (to 33:3, s.v. הרצועות שחורות) is undecided regarding whether the entire length of the straps must be black for the *t'fillin* to be valid,  or whether the *t'fillin* are valid if even the minimum required length for *r'tzu'os* are black (see *Shulchan Aruch* OC 27:8,11 for the minimum required lengths). Rabbi Kaganoff [cites](http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1775) R' Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld as ruling that if even the majority of the *r'tzu'os* are black, the *t'fillin* remain valid. (This may refer to a contiguous length of the *r'tzu'os*, possibly beginning from the top down).

Although most *poskim* maintain that it is also a *mitzvah* for the *batim* to be black (see for example *Shulchan Aruch* OC 32:40), there is disagreement regarding whether they must be black for the *t'fillin* to be valid. The *Mishna B'rura* (32:184) cites multiple *acharonim* who rule stringently but say that a person may rely on the lenient opinions when *t'fillin* with completely black *batim* are not available.

According to the *Shulchan Aruch* (OC 33:4), it is preferable to paint the *t'fillin lishmah*, while the *Rama* (ad loc.) holds that the straps must be painted *lishmah* and that it is proper to paint the *batim lishmah*. Since the *Rama* does not hold that lack of paint on the *batim* invalidates the *t'fillin*, he writes that a lack of *lishmah* does not invalidate the painting of the *batim*.

Comment: My favorite Mishna Brura! OC 32 - קפה שחור